# How to find a control (with no name no id) of a webBrowser code behind

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working with Visual Studio 2005 Visual Basic Windows Application. I need to find a button and click on it from code behind. **But there is no name and no id of the button.**

When I see the source of the web page button is like that;

```
<input type="submit" value="Devam Et" onclick="return validatee();" style="background:#F79F81;font-weight:bold">
```

I'm trying to click using .outerHTML like this;

```
If WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(k).OuterHtml = "<input type="submit" value="Devam Et" onclick="return validatee();" style="background:#F79F81;font-weight:bold">" Then
     WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(k).InvokeMember("click")
     Exit For
End If
```

But I couldnt manage to be succesful so far. Because, I think, this control is seen in a different format from code behind. I was succesful on this on some buttons before (by changing the format,changing the order of type, style, etc.)

There should be some better way to do this without using .outerHTML.

Comment: That doesn't look like winforms and it doesn't sound like it's VBA either (visual basic for applications).  It looks like asp.net.  Perhaps you could change the tags?

Comment: no, it is a windows application in visual basic and I use webBrowser control to navigate the page. but, right, its not a vba

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the forms, at least that's better than iterating through all the elements on the page. The example below is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.forms.aspx#Y106

```
For Each FormElem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Forms
    FormElem.InvokeMember("reset")
Next
```